# Dates format not localized in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I'm a beginner in OctoberCMS and I have a date format issue. I use custom "date" field in all my plugins.

When I have a "date" field in a plugin database, the date displayed on the front end is not localized in fr but in english.

But when I use a default created_at timestamp database field and if I use a default from "created_at" in my model form, the date displayed on the front-end is localized...

I've tested twig extensions to try to force localization but it doesn't change anything...

Here is the code.

```
{% for press in presses %}
<div class="container-fluid-sans fond-liste">
            <div class="container-fluid-sans bloc-liste">
                  <!-- Project One -->
                  <div class="row align-items-center pr-5">
                    <div class="col-12 presse">
<div class="text-left mb-2">
{% for spectacle in press.spectacles %}
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-liste mr-2"> 
.{{spectacle.title}}
</span>
{% endfor %}
<span class="liste-texte"> . 
{{press.date | date('j F Y') }}, par {{press.author}}
</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Would you like to show your code where you are retrieving dates ?

Comment: And for the date which field you have taken?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not customised locale in config/app.php?
line 58 `'locale' => 'en'` by default

Comment: Hello, I did actually. Thanks

Comment: Its a wierd thing with the dates, I've setup the locale in my `config/app.php` and when using twig `date` modifier the blog date is localized but any other isn't